# Google Cloud Messaging Server Id - lifetime

Tags: java, android, key, google-cloud-messaging

Today I wanted to add GCM to my Android application.
In the Google developer console I found this line:

```
Aktiv bis 14.12.2014, 14:07:00
```

respectively

```
Active to 14.12.2014, 14:07:00
```

Have I to regenerate the server key daily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know that's not the case. You just need to fetch one initially.